# Gives CORS error while sending the request form React JS to PHP which are deployed in differed hosts

Tags: php, reactjs

am new to react js application development.

we have two application from front end side. One is developed in Anuglar JS and another is developed in React JS. These two are hosted in different URL's. These two application should have to communication with PHP for getting common data, which is deployed in another host name.

Here the problem is from angular JS am able to hit php, with out any CORS error, and we got the response.

But from my react JS application am not able to send request to PHP. It gives CORS erros.

In Anuglar JS, one one request is going to the server , here there is not options request.But in React JS we have options request also.

Could you please help me , what changes have to do either  front end or back end.

Thank you,
SrinivasaRao.CH

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: in the backend you'll have to allow the origin of your frontend react application.

Comment: Show code of your http client (axios, superagent..) from where you're requesting.

Comment: This is not the fault of ReactJS, although you seem to be comparing it to Angular. There will be some other factor as well. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS if you're new to CORS. Basically if your request is cross-origin (different server and/or port number from your page to the server where you send the AJAX request) then your server needs to set some headers in its response which allows the request to come from the correct origin.